# react-router v4 params and bread crumb component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

React router works like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  {/* the root router creates an "empty" match, so match.params = {} */}
  <Route path='/album/:albumID' component={Album}>
    {/* match.params = { albumID: '123' } */}
    <Album>
      {/* match.path = '/album/:albumID' */}
      <Route path={`${match.path}/song/:songID`} component={Song}>
        {/* match.params = { albumID: '123', songID: '456' } */}
        <Song>
```

The routes above have dynamic parameters.  The params are only avilable in the specific route

I wanted to create a generic `BreadCrumbs` component that would render outside of the relative route.

This is not possible in react-router v4 because the params are only available relative to the specific route.

There does not appear to be anyway outside of parsing the url of handling htis.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

This is really not good.

Comment: Does something like this work? https://codesandbox.io/s/3r0q2pzq6m

Comment: only works for one route unfortunately, I need all routes really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to take advantage of React Router's v4 dynamic routes:

I ended up doing something like this:

```
const routes: RoutePaths[] = [
  '/route/one/?:foo',
  //etc
];

    export class BreadCrumbProxy extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any> & DispatchProp<any>> {
      render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
              {routes.map(route => (
                <Route
                  key={route.toString()}
                  exact
                  path={route}
                  render={({ match }: RouteComponentProps<any>) => <ApplicationHeader {...match} />}
                />
              ))}
            </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

This passes the contextual match into the BreadCrumb component.